# Different datatype values in an array

Tags: php, arrays, data-structures

Why php array allows different datatype to reside in an array as array should contains data of same datatype but that is not the case with php?

For example: - We can add ints, strings, floats, all of these in a single array.

Comment: An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates values to keys.  And a value in PHP has no a fixed datatype.

Comment: Arrays have nothing to do with data types in PHP. Check out [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) which explains arrays the best.

Answer (score 0):

An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates values to keys. This type is optimized for several different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack, queue, and probably more. As array values can be other arrays, trees and multidimensional arrays are also possible.